# How do we do authentications in web applications?

Tags: session, authentication, node.js, session-cookies

**Sorry, I wrote a lot to explain my situation, If you don't have time or not in mood to read all these just jump to the questions. Even answering one of them helps my situation, thanks :D**
I'm trying to write a web application in node.js, but since I'm too new to web, I don't know how to write the web login system. I don't want to use basic or digest http authentications, I want it like normal login systems with http forms and different pages shows different content for different types of users. I searched a bit, I know the basics, but they're not enough.
This is what I got:

1. We check the user and pass from the
   POST data in the database
2. If correct we give the client a new session, and save it in a database.
3. The client saves the session as a cookie and sends it in each page request.
4. The server checks the session and gives the content intended for the user.

Here's the part I don't know:

- How do we generate a session?
- How do we send it to the client?
- How is it saved in cookies?
- When is it supposed to expire?
- What happens if it is expired? What
  should we do?
- Is there anything else that I should
  know?

If you can please, give me some examples in node.
Thank you in advance :D

Comment: Please don't write your own login-system for websites. You can do it for learning, but I am going to tell you right now that your site will be very insecure. You should use something like https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth which uses third-parties like facebook, twitter, google to handle the authentication for you. They have got security-experts on board that know how to keep a system save and what to do when compromised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A session is simply a unique key (session ID) associated with an object/array, this way you can connect data to a user of your site.
- You send the session ID to the client as a cookie, once sent, the client sends its session ID to your server with every HTTP request.
- You send the HTTP `Set-Cookie` header (`Set-Cookie: sessionid=abcdefg38974`).
- You can make it expire when you want it to, when the browser closes or after for example a year (this would keep you logged in for a year, after which you'll have to login again).
- When a cookie expires it is simply thrown away, on the serverside it will just look like the user doesn't have a session ID set yet so he has to log in again.
- You should know of things like session hijacking (stealing someone else's session ID). Have a look at it.

Little example, it might increate the visit number twice each time you request because your browser also requests `/favicon.ico`. Keep in mind that this example is not very safe as session hijacking is possible, this also keeps all sessions in memory and forgets them when the server is restarted. It would be wise to save sessions to a database.

```js
var http = require('http');

var sessions = {};
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var ssid;
    var session;

    if (req.headers.cookie) {
        // Cookie already set, read it
        var parts = req.headers.cookie.split('=');
        ssid = parts[1];

        // Is the session id known to us?
        if (typeof(sessions[ssid]) != "undefined") {
            session = sessions[ssid];

            console.log('Loaded session with id ' + ssid);
        }
    }

    if (typeof(session) == "undefined") {
        // No cookie set, make one
        ssid = Math.random();
        session = {
            'visitNumber': 0
        }

        console.log('Created session with id ' + ssid);
    }

    session.visitNumber++;

    // Respond to the browser
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Set-Cookie': 'ssid=' + ssid
    });

    res.end('Visit number: ' + session.visitNumber + '\n');

    // Save the changes we have made to the session data
    sessions[ssid] = session;

}).listen(8080);
```